# Toggle won't stay open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have images (`.rv_button`) that are acting as buttons to toggle the div's below (`#reveal`). I want to hover over the button to open the div but right now I can't get the div to stay open. Can someone help me with this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide the div
  jQuery('#reveal').hide();
  jQuery('.rv_button').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#reveal").fadeToggle()(slow, swing, callback);
    jQuery('.rv_button').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Comment: What is your HTML?

Comment: with multiple buttons, you have to iterate through them with a statement like `if this.hasClass("open")? do something : do something else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `toggleClass()`, on `mousenter`, remove the `open` class from all of the buttons and add it to `e.target` or `$(this)`. And on `mouseout` just remove it from all the buttons.

Also, remove `(slow, swing, callback)` or use them as arguments in `fadeToggle()`.

e.g.

`jQuery("#reveal").fadeToggle('slow')`;

And to keep the div to stay open, just wrap the buttons and div in a container and listen for the `mouseout` event on it instead of the buttons themselves.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide the div
  $('#reveal').hide();
  $('.rv_button').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.rv_button').removeClass('open');
    $(e.target).addClass('open');
    $("#reveal").fadeIn();
  });
  $('.container').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.rv_button').removeClass('open');
    $("#reveal").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
}

#reveal {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: beige;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.rv_button {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: brown;
  width: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.open {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="rv_button">Button 1</div>
  <div class="rv_button">Button 2</div>
  <div class="rv_button">Button 3</div>
  <div id="reveal">Reveal</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @thingEvery I'm sorry, I'm a Javascript newbie. I don't know about the e.target or $(this) and how to use. Can you explain further?

Comment: @funkyc123 I've updated my answer with an example for you.

Comment: Thank you @thingEvery, though it looks like I may not have made my goal clear.I am trying to get the reveal div to stay open when I hover down to it,

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Works perfectly